# ComboBoxColumn default value from datasource

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am writing simple vb app and what I want to do is to pass value from database (which is given as datasource) to default value of my comboBox column

this is what i do now:

pass data to `DataGridView`

`DataGridView2.DataSource = source`

which is working very well and it fetch data from database and fill whole table.

Question is: I want to make one of columns  as ComboBox. But also i want to set default value as value from database. It is how i make combo box columns:

```
Dim comboboxColumn As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
          comboboxColumn.Items.Add("sleep")
            comboboxColumn.Items.Add("stay")
            comboboxColumn.Items.Add("Go")
            comboboxColumn.Name = "state"
' comboboxColumn.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue //WHAT can I do HERE?
            DataGridView2.Columns.Add(comboboxColumn)
```

Could you guys share some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DataTable and set it to the combobox. Then you'll have to set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False` and create the other columns manually. In the example bellow I created the dataTable by myself, but it could be a DataTable.Load from your database query

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()

With dt
    .Columns.Add("Value", GetType(String))
    .Rows.Add("sleep")
    .Rows.Add("stay")
    .Rows.Add("go")
    .AcceptChanges()
End With

With comboboxColumn
    .HeaderText = "State"
    .DataSource = dt
    .DataPropertyName = "STATE"
    .DisplayMember = "Value"
    .ValueMember = "Value"
End With
```